# xubuntu 18.04 login screen to all displays

Tags: xubuntu, login, multiple-monitors, display

By accident or not, on my PC at work, xubuntu login screen showed on both displays. Every ware else it shows only on single display and I can make it jump to a second display by dragging the mouse.
To show login screen on all displays is good feature.
Where this configuration is stored? How do I make it by default?